# Set max-execution-time on a function

Tags: javascript, cordova, pdfmake

I am generating PDF files using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) on client side (a cordova app).

The more complex the document definition is the longer *pdfmake* takes to produce the document.

Thus, my intention is to put a hard limit on how long it takes for *pdfmake* to produce the document, something like what [timeout](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command do in bash, and indicate to user if it failed to complete.

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
runFor(10, function(){  // run this function for a maximum of 10s
  pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).getBase64(function(b64buff){
     //do something with the result
  });
}, ontimeout);
```

Comment: yes, there probably is. Hope that helps

Comment: please show your function, is it a loop, recursive, ajax?

Comment: Basically impossible to answer without the code. You are going to have to change it somehow, impossible to know how without seeing the code. It is like telling a mechanic I want to improve the performance without telling him what the car is or even letting him see it and you show up with a moped.

Comment: @Kaiido not what OP is asking....

Comment: Well aware of the vagueness of my question. Trying to workout a few details here. English and Javascript is not my first language

Comment: why does this have an upvote. It is a terrible question

Comment: @Kaiido exactly, the function don't have to complete. I simply want to set hard limit to how long it can run.

Comment: you still have not answered why it's running for a long time and what the functions purpose is.

Comment: @synthet1c it's a call to pdfMake functions. I've added the details up there

Comment: @Kaiido I figure if i spread my net wide, I can catch a few pointers. Right now I don't even know the keyword/search term to google.

Comment: No, the more precise you are about your use case, the easiest it is for us to find a possible solution. I drastically edited your question. Feel free to [edit] furthermore if you think I missed something, or even to [rollback] the edit.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks yours is better. I'm now looking into promises, still not really sure I'm going the right direction

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is in JavaScript, the setInterval function.

```
var i =0;
setInterval(function(){i++;console.log(i)},1000);
```

This snippet increases i by 1 every second. Now in the function you want to execute, make a check on i to see if it is big enough to divert the code to a interrupt. Just make sure to reset i when you restart the function.

Comment: Problem is that in many cases (the OP's example included), You are not able to check some counter in the long running task.

Comment: Though I posted this answer a long time ago, a clarifying limitation is that we are working with one thread in both OPs question and my answer. If you want to monitor a function to stop at a certain point without passing that control to the function, then I don't see any other option but to use a second execution thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to change the function. Maybe it could take a condition as a parameter.

Depending on what it was doing that takes 'forever' you could spawn a child process that runs the function then kill the process after a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry this solution is not as generic as you or future readers might want it to be, but it does work, and I can't come with a better idea yet...

The [WebWorker interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) as a [`terminate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate) method, which will stop the Worker's execution immediately once called by the main thread.
We can use this to start a timer on the main thread that will call this `Worker.terminate` method when the timeout threshold has been reached.

This is not really generic, because it implies that your code must be able to run inside a Worker.
But you are lucky since it seems *pdfmake* library can.

So you could write it like this:

**pdfmakeWorkerScript.js**

```
// first import needed assets
self.importScripts('pdfmake.min.js');
self.importScripts('vfs_fonts.js');

self.onmessage = function(e) {
  if(e.data.docDefinition){
    pdfMake.createPdf(e.data.docDefinition).getBase64(function(b64) {
      self.postMessage(b64);
    });
  }
};
```

in **main page**

```
function generatePDFinLessThan(docDefinition, maxTimeInSec, onsuccess, ontimeout){
  var worker = new Worker('pdfmakeWorkerScript.js');
  var timer = setTimeout(stopWorker, maxTimeInSec * 1000);
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if(typeof onsuccess === 'function')
        onsuccess(e.data);
  }
  function stopWorker() {
    worker.terminate();
    if(typeof ontimeout === 'function')
        ontimeout();
  }
  worker.postMessage({docDefinition: docDefinition});
}

// usage
var docDefinition = {...};
generatePDFinLessThan(docDefinition, 10, function onsuccess(data) {...}, function ontimeout() {...});
```

And a modified version so that it works in StackSnippets:

```js
const workerURL = generateWorkerURL(); // should normally just be a string url pointing to your worker's .js

const docDefinition = {
  content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake'
};

function generatePDFinLessThan(max_duration, onsuccess, ontimeout) {
  let timer = null;
  const worker = new Worker(workerURL);
  worker.onmessage = e => {
    if (e.data === "assets ready") { // for slow connections
      startTimer();
      return;
    }
    if (e.data.type === "success"){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if(typeof onsuccess === 'function') {
        onsuccess(e.data.data);
      }
    }
  };
  worker.postMessage({
    docDefinition: docDefinition,
    // demo only!
    waitingTime: waitingInput.value * 1000
    // end demo only
  });

  function startTimer() {
    console.log('assets ready'); // rawgit is really long for me...
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      worker.terminate();
      if (typeof ontimeout === 'function') {
        ontimeout();
      }
    }, max_duration * 1000);
  }
}

btn.onclick = e => generatePDFinLessThan(+maxTimeInput.value, onsuccess, ontimeout);

function onsuccess(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

function ontimeout() {
  console.error('operation timed out');
}

// demo only!
function generateWorkerURL() {
  const script = document.querySelector('script[type="worker-script"]');
  const blob = new Blob([script.textContent], {
    type: 'application/javascript'
  });
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
  /* pdfmake generation in a worker */ 
  const pdfmake_baseURI = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bpampuch/pdfmake/build/";
  // first import needed assets
  self.importScripts(pdfmake_baseURI + 'pdfmake.min.js');
  self.importScripts(pdfmake_baseURI + 'vfs_fonts.js');

  self.postMessage('assets ready');

  onmessage = e => {
    if(e.data.docDefinition){
      // for demo only!
      wait(e.data.waitingTime); 
      // end for demo only
      pdfMake.createPdf(e.data.docDefinition).getBase64(b64 => {
        self.postMessage({type: 'success', data: b64});
      });
    }
  };

  // for demo only!
  function wait(dur) {
    const now = performance.now();
    while(performance.now() - now < dur){}
  }
</script>
<button id="btn">generate pdf</button><br>
<label>Maximum execution time (in sec) <input type="number" id="maxTimeInput" value="5"></label><br>
<label>Waiting time in worker (in sec) <input type="number" id="waitingInput" value="0"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Promise.all with two promises.

**One promise** will fire a function that will 1) start a timer to reject which will end Promise.all, and 2) a function that will check a boolean every 50ms if the target function is done.

The **Second promise** will fire the target function and it will set the boolean to true when done

The target function should be an async function

```
async function runFor(maxTimeMS, funcAsync) {
  let completed = false;
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setInterval(() => {
          if (completed) {
            resolve();
          }
        }, 50); // check if completed every 50ms
        setTimeout(reject, maxTimeMS); // timeMS is max time to wait for func
      }),
      new Promise( async () => await funcAsync() )
        .then(() => { completed = true; })
    ]);
  } catch (e) {
    // if funcAsync does not complete, you will get an exception here
  }
}
```